# Convert implicitly in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is possible to convert implicitly like this?
For example:

Screen.as:

```
public class Screen
{
    protected var screen_:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function Screen() {}
}
```

Main.as:

```
public function Main()
{
    Screen screen = new Screen();
    addToStage(screen); // somehow return Sprite `screen_`
}

private function addToStage(child:DisplayObject)
{
    stage.addChild(screen);
}
```

**EDITED:**

So it's impossible. But at least, can I somehow override `addChild()` method to pass an argument of `Screen` or other classes?

Comment: Concerning your edit, give [this question a look-see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384611/as3-override-addchild-test-for-type)

Comment: Note that even of you'd implement `addChild()` so that `screen_` will end up on the display list of a something, that something would still be able to reach it by calling `getChildAt()` - so why protecting something that'll be publicly available if used? Even more, the contents of your `screen_` will be accessible by that link.

Answer (score 0):

Converting, not really. But with a simple getter you can still get access to the Sprite.

Screen.as:

```
public class Screen
{
    protected var screen_:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function Screen() {}

    public function get sprite():Sprite{
        return screen_;
    }
}
```

Main.as:

```
public function Main()
{
    Screen screen = new Screen();
    var sprite:Sprite = addToStage(screen); //your desired Sprite
}

private function addToStage(child:DisplayObject):Sprite
{
    stage.addChild(screen);
    return screen.sprite;
}
```

Comment: I have already added a method `addTo(parent:DisplayObjectContainer)`. You just need to pass in the `stage` like this: `screen.addTo(stage);`. By the way, I have edited my question to ask a lil' addition question.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to effectively hide `screen_` from outside whatever you do. The primary reason is that there is a way to publicly enumerate the display list, the interface uses [`DisplayObjectContainer.numChildren`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#numChildren) and `DisplayObjectContainer.getChildAt()`, which are both public. So your best action would be extend `Sprite` with your `Screen` class, drop that protected property and use `this` whenever you need to do something as a sprite. This way you will not need any hacks to represent your class as whatever it isn't like and be able to comply with base of [`SOLID`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principle.